# DRY I dont want to repeat this CSS code with ::after

Tags: html, css, sass

I wrote code which is running perfectly, but I would like to not repeat scss code and I tried but I'm unsuccesful so far:

```
item { <--css class
 width: 100px;
}
 &-firstchild {<--first child of "item" class
        &::after{
          width: 60px;
          content: '';
          display: block;
          margin-left: 20px;
          border-bottom: 2px solid $ea-color-red-base;
        } 
&-secondchild{<--second child of "item" class
        &::after{
          width: 60px;
          content: '';
          display: block;
          margin-left: 20px;
          border-bottom: 2px solid $ea-color-blue-base;
        }
```

This is the common scss for all the children in ::after:

```
      width: 60px;
      content: '';
      display: block;
      margin-left: 20px;
```

I would like to group it and not repeat since I have several children.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to repeat the selectors you can use the [@extend rule](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend) and a [placeholder selector](http://www.sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/placeholder-selectors):

```
%childStyles {
   width: 60px;
   content: '';
   display: block;
   margin-left: 20px;
}

.item {
    width: 100px;
 
    &-firstchild {
        &::after {
           @extend %childStyles;
           border-bottom: 2px solid $ea-color-red-base;
        } 
    }

    &-secondchild {
        &::after {
           @extend %childStyles;
           border-bottom: 2px solid $ea-color-blue-base;
        }
    }
}
```

The extended styles will compile as:

```
.item-secondchild::after, .item-firstchild::after {
   width: 60px;
   content: "";
   display: block;
   margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.item {
  width: 100px;

  &-firstchild, &-secondchild {
    &::after{
      width: 60px;
      content: '';
      display: block;
      margin-left: 20px;
    }
  }
  &-firstchild::after {
    border-bottom: 2px solid $ea-color-red-base;
  }
  &-secondchild::after {
    border-bottom: 2px solid $ea-color-blue-base;
  }
}
```